# Regarding window movement and refresh in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm exploring with a modified program based on ncurses [window tutorial](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/windows.html) to move a window without deleting and remaking it each time using `mvwin`, and have run into the following questions:

1. Moving the window leaves behind a trace of the old window (see example below code). I'm used to that, and needing to clear old characters with `erase` (comment 1 in code) or printing a newline at the start of each line. Looking at the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/touchwin), this looks like something a call to `touchwin`/`touchline` is supposed to solve, but don't. **First question: what does `touchwin` do if not that?**
2. Erasing the entire screen, then reprinting the first line and moving the window will display the first line, but not the window after refresh. I tried to force displaying the moved window with `redrawwin`, but the only thing that worked is adding another refresh right after erasing the screen (comment 2 in code). I dislike that method, it causes screen flickering, and it feels like there has to be a better method. **Second question: is there a way to display a moving window after erasing the screen without another refresh?**
3. In comment 3 in the code, after moving the window and reprinting the first line, calling `refresh` will display only the written line and not the moved window, but calling `wrefresh(my_win)` will display both the moved window and the printed line. **Third question: why does `wrefresh` displays things outside the refreshed window?**

example code:

```
int main()
{   WINDOW *my_win;
    int startx, starty, width, height;
    int ch, err;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    height = 3;
    width = 10;
    starty = (LINES - height) / 2;
    startx = (COLS - width) / 2;
    
    refresh();
    my_win = create_newwin(height, width, starty, startx);

    while((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(4))
    {
        erase();  // <--(1)
        refresh();  // <--(2)

        switch(ch)
        {   
            case KEY_LEFT:
                mvprintw(0, 0, "moving window to position (%d, %d)", starty, --startx);
                err = mvwin(my_win, starty, startx);
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                mvprintw(0, 0, "moving window to position (%d, %d)", starty, ++startx);
                err = mvwin(my_win, starty, startx);
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                mvprintw(0, 0, "moving window to position (%d, %d)", --starty, startx);
                err = mvwin(my_win, starty, startx);
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                mvprintw(0, 0, "moving window to position (%d, %d)", ++starty, startx);
                err = mvwin(my_win, starty, startx);
                break;
            default:
                mvprintw(0, 0, "UNKNOWN INPUT!");
        }

        if (err != NCURSES_OK)
        {
            mvprintw(0, 0, "Error %d while moving window", err);
        }

        wrefresh(my_win);  // <--(3)
    }
        
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

exmaple for "leftover characters" after moving the window left twice:

```
moving window to position (6, 32)





                                ┌────────┐┐┐
                                │        │││
                                └────────┘┘┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that curses does not manage *overlapping* windows. The window which you are moving using `mvwin` overlaps with `stdscr`.  When you move it, `stdscr` is not repainted to reflect the fact that `my_win` used to occupy some parts of the screen which it no longer does.

The `panel` library is designed to solve this problem nicely, but as a workaround, you can ensure that `stdscr` is repainted by using `touchwin` and then `refresh`.  Repainting just a line is not effective unless you limit the program to moving the window up and down -- never left or right.

The ncurses test-programs include one which demonstrates how to use `mvwin` ([test/movewindow.c](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/movewindow.c)).  The test-program keeps track of all of the windows and calls `refresh_all` after calling [`mvwin`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/4d13ad3611c4206c0ee251e492a7f51d9ef28437/test/movewindow.c#L458):

```c
static void
repaint_one(WINDOW *win)
{
    touchwin(win);
    wnoutrefresh(win);
}

static void
refresh_all(WINDOW *win)
{
    unsigned n;

    for (n = 0; n < num_windows; ++n) {
        if (all_windows[n].child != win) {
            repaint_one(all_windows[n].child);
        }
    }

    repaint_one(win);
    doupdate();
}
```

By the way, the "documentation" referred to in the question and suggested answer is very old - from [2009](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses).  Your local machine probably has manual pages installed which are newer than that.

Answer (score 2):

In (n)curses, *refreshing* means to draw the data associated with a given window to the physical screen<sup>1</sup>. As an optimization, data that has already been *marked as drawn* will not be draw again.

*Updating* a position in a window with new data removes any marker from that position. `erase` (`werase`) *updates* every position in the window with blanks (removing all markers).

`touchwin` forcefully removes every marker within the associated window, without changing any data, so that the next time it is *refreshed* all of its content is redrawn. `touchline` does the same for a set of lines.

`mvwin(my_win, ...)` and `wrefresh(my_win);` changes the data associated with `my_win`, and draws it out to the physical screen. `stdscr` has no idea this has happened, and does not know to redraw the positions previously "behind" the other window that were already marked as drawn. This is why you must remove those markers in some way.

`wrefresh(my_win);` is not refreshing both `my_win` and `stdscr`, but rather `getch` performs `refresh` because of `mvprintw` (an *update*).

From [`getch(3)`](https://man.openbsd.org/getch.3):

> If  the  window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the last call to **wrefresh**, **wrefresh** will be called before another character is read.

Note that all of these interactions depend heavily on the *order* in which the functions are called. A typical order would be to:

1. (optionally) erase / clear / touch the window(s)
2. update the window(s) with new data
3. refresh (draw) the window(s)<sup>2</sup>

Where as in your program you follow this order:

1. refresh `stdscr` (via `getch`, after the first iteration)
2. erase `stdscr`
3. refresh `stdscr`
4. update `stdcr`
5. update `my_win`
6. refresh `my_win`

As pointed out above, the blocking nature of `getch`, and the fact that it refreshes the standard window, is what is allowing you to actually *see* the lines produced by `mvprintw` (otherwise you have an update -> erase for `stdscr`).

---

Here is a bit of a refactored example:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

#define clearline(y) do { move(y, 0); clrtoeol(); } while (0)

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    curs_set(0);

    const int height = 3;
    const int width = 10;
    int y = (LINES - height) / 2;
    int x = (COLS - width) / 2;

    WINDOW *my_win = newwin(height, width, y, x);
    box(my_win, 0, 0);
    mvwaddstr(my_win, 1, 2, "Hello!");

    while (1) {
        /* draw our 'background', then our boxed window */
        refresh();
        wrefresh(my_win);

        int ch = getch();

        /* touch the 'background' lines behind our boxed window,
         * AFTER `getch` would have redrawn, but BEFORE updating `y` */
        touchline(stdscr, y, height);

        switch (ch) {
            case KEY_UP:    --y; break;
            case KEY_DOWN:  ++y; break;
            case KEY_LEFT:  --x; break;
            case KEY_RIGHT: ++x; break;
            default:
        }

        if ('q' == ch || ERR == ch)
            break;

        /* `touchline` above, and this `clearline` are a small optimization over
         * just calling `erase()` right here */
        clearline(0);

        mvprintw(0, 0, "moving window to position (%d, %d)", y, x);

        if (OK != mvwin(my_win, y, x))
            mvprintw(1, 0, "Error moving window <%p>", (void *) my_win);
        else
            clearline(1);

    }

    delwin(my_win);
    endwin();
}
```

*(80x10 terminal)*

```
moving window to position (3, 34)


                                  ┌────────┐
                                  │ Hello! │
                                  └────────┘
```

---

<sup>1. This is a minor simplification: there is actually a virtual screen in-between the window->physical screen pipeline. See: [`refresh(3)`](https://man.openbsd.org/refresh.3) for details.</sup>

<sup>2. A *later* refresh will overwrite any data drawn by an *earlier* refresh, where there would be a collision on the physical screen.</sup>

Comment: To follow your point about `touchX`, why does touching the first line still leave undeleted marks (for example `)` when moving window from position 100 to 99)? Wouldn't `touchline(stdscr, 0, 1)` clear that mark so that it won't be printed on next refresh?

Comment: No, *touching* a window's position simply marks it as being changed (even if it wasn't actually). `touchline(stdscr, 0, 1)` like saying "Hey, let's pretend this line was changed, and force it to be redrawn next refresh". Another way to think about it is that a function like `addch` is *changing* the data associated with a position *and then* marking that position as having changed - requiring a redraw. Two separate steps, where *touching* a position is to only do the second step.